# Python, как перезаписать CSV файл в папке с сохранением имени?

Tags: python, csv

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему такой код не работает?
usr_eater - функция, которая обрабатывает исходный файл и возвращает датафрейм, который я хочу в формате csv переписать в исходный файл.Но в итоге всегда получаются файлы с содержанием "1, 2, 3".

Как перезаписать файлы в папке с сохранением их имени?

Дополнение:
У нас есть папка с файлами-юзерлогами в формате .txt. Я хочу написать код, который будет по очереди открывать каждый файл, группировать данные по значению в первом столбце и сохранять эту группировку в исходный файл, то есть как бы перезапишет его. В итоге чтобы получилась та же папка с файлами в формате .txt, но уже со сгруппированными значениями.

Функция, которая откроет txt и сгруппирует данные написана, но у меня сложности с пониманием как дальше в цикле организовать поочередное открытие файла и применение к функции и перезапись.

То есть я открываю файл с помощью "open", применяю "write", но он не дает записать туда, потому что у меня результат функции - это не строки, а датафрейм.

Я пробую применять просто сохранение в csv с помощью "to_csv(encoding='cp1251')", но получается только "1, 2, 3".

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторон у двигаться? Нужно ли применять open и close, если я пользуюсь to.csv?

```
def usr_eater(directory):
    df = pd.read_csv(
    directory, 
    delimiter=' ', 
    names=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'],
    encoding_errors='ignore',
    encoding='cp1251'
    )
    df_grouped = df[df['3']=="Зашел"].groupby(['1', '2'])['3'].count().sort_values(ascending=False)
    return df_grouped
    

for f in Path(r"C:\userlog").glob("*.txt"):
    file = open(f, "w")
    a = usr_eater(f)
    csv_data = a.to_csv(encoding='cp1251')
    f = file.write(csv_data)
    file.close()
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код функции `usr_eater`

Comment: @alex Спасибо, код функции добавлен!

Comment: не ясно, в чём у вас проблема. вы читаете файл как csv, а потом записываете прочитанное в него же как csv. может быть, под словосочетанием «формат csv» вы подразумеваете не формат **содержимого** файла, а суффикс `.csv` в **имени** файла? изложите, пожалуйста, чего вы ожидаете от своей программы, прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit].

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Спасибо за обратную связь, вопрос дополнен, надеюсь, теперь он более конкретно звучит)